# Replace MultiPoint, GeometryCollection & LineString geometries in shapefile with Point geometries

Tags: python, point, linestring, multipoint

I have a geopandas dataframe that contains shapely MultiPoint, LineString, GeometryCollection and Point geometries. Cannot save the the geopandas because of this neither perform other operations (extract values from raster).

[image]

Here is a sample of the shapefile

```
dfinter['geometry'].to_dict()

{0: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ec57c82190>,
 1: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ec5fb11c70>,
 2: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ec58f452b0>,
 3: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ec5ffa8d60>,
 4: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ec5ffa8be0>,
 5: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ec5ffa8bb0>,
 30: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x1ec5ffaf4f0>,
 42: <shapely.geometry.collection.GeometryCollection at 0x1ec5ffafa00>,
 64: <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x1ec5ffaf7f0>,
 75: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x1ec5ff7fb80>,
 168: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x1ec5ffa5eb0>,
 179: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x1ec5ff9dee0>,
 180: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1ec5ff9de80>,
 368: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x1ec5ff975e0>,
 369: <shapely.geometry.multipoint.MultiPoint at 0x1ec5ff97640>}
```

I get this error while trying to save the file

```
RuntimeError: GDAL Error: Attempt to write non-point (MULTIPOINT) geometry to point shapefile. 
 
 Failed to write record: {'id': '30', 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'first_line': 3, 'second_line': 648}, 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPoint', 'coordinates': ((3.1417110090308236, 10.56099587036708), (3.1417150506463645, 10.561003192402628))}}
```

I tried this code to convert the MultiPoint geometries in dfinter geopandas

```
[(Point(pt.x, pt.y)) for pt in dfinter.loc[30][2]]
```

I need to iterate this on all rows containing MultiPoint and find a way to also convert LineString & GeometryCollection to Point geometries.

Comment: Can you share your data with us?

Comment: Done, I just shared a sample of the geometries of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used [GeoSeries.representative_point()](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.representative_point.html) to simply get Points related to each geometry.

```
dfinter['geometry'] = dfinter.representative_point()
```

I also found that you could use [geopandas.GeoSeries.explode()](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.explode.html) to convert MultiPoint to Point.